# setting up an https site on windows 7 for WCF testing

Tags: wcf, iis

I am learning WCF and I need to set up an https site on my windows seven machine. Is this possible? I have googled multiple variations of "https windows 7" etc but haven't found any useful information. When I select https in the drop down from IIS it won't let me click next. Can someone point me in the right direction regarding this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to configure your service for https on windows 7 machine do the following:

1.Open IIS. Create a new website by doing a right click on the sites folder and select Add new website.

1. Now the add new website popup comes up. enter the details and in the bindings section select Type to be https and the port would change to 443 and a SSL certificate dropdown is shown.
2. Select a certificate from the dropdown that is used to secure your communication channel for this website or applications in this website.

Once you perform the above steps you have created a website that listens on https.

NOTE: The certificates in the SSL Certificate dropdown are available only when you install the certificates to the appropriate store.

Comment: Uhm, yeah - I got there but in Windows 7 ultimate I can't enter the host name and the SSL certificate drop down is empty, my only option is "Not selected". :(

Comment: Duh, for those who might be as blockheaded as me in the future. First go to SSL settings and create a self signed certificate, it will then show up in the drop down when you create a new site.